# Which build system will do this the most 'naturally'?

Tags: build, makefile, cmake, build-system

Instead of the flat structure my code currently has, I want to organize it into modules contained in sub-folders (and perhaps sub-sub folders if the modules get big enough).

Each module will have one or more translation units which will each produce a .o file.
The final target would be to mash up all these object files into a static library (for now).

I am using plain 'make' and it is already complicated enough.
Is there a system in which the specified model comes naturally or with much less effort compared to writing makefiles by hand ? 
(If you are going to recommend cmake, I need some hints as I have already tried and could not come up with a good solution.)

Comment: What was the problem with `make`?

Comment: Cumbersome and I think ignorance on my part. I can't find a simple way to do this using make .

Comment: Ok - answered for GNU make.  Let me know if you want any more explanation.  I'm sure somebody who knows more about cmake or something will be along to answer eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some paraphrased bits from my current project's makefile that may help you out with good old fashioned GNU make:

```
SOURCEDIR := dir1 dir2/subdir1 dir3 dir4 dir5/subdir1 dir6/subdir1
SOURCES := $(foreach srcdir,$(SOURCEDIR),$(wildcard $(srcdir)/*.c))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,build/%.o,$(SOURCES))
OBJDIRS := $(addprefix build/,$(SOURCEDIR))
MAKEDEPS := $(patsubst %.c,build/%.d,$(SOURCES))

all: example

$(OBJDIRS):
    -mkdir -p $@

build: $(OBJDIRS)

build/%.o : %.c | build
    cc -MMD -c -o $@ $<

example: $(OBJECTS)
    cc -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

-include $(MAKEDEPS)
```

In essence, it builds all of the source files found in the designated directories into object files located in subdirectories of the `build` directory in a hierarchy that parallels their source directory layout (important if multiple source files have the same name) and then links the results into an executable `example`.

As a bonus, dynamic dependency generation and inclusion via the `MAKEDEPS` variable and clang's `-MMD` flag.

Comment: Thank you. That wildcard is what I tripped at.

Comment: I'll eventually(if needed) have to modify it to use recursive makefiles within the folders, but that shouldn't pose much of a problem.

Comment: Recursive makefiles have their own set of pain, but depending on how big your project is it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon your purposes: Build packages are generally intended for the audience rather than the performer.  Often, they take into consideration the disparate environments into which people deploy.  I played around with 'tup,' which seemed more a way of generating an executable as quickly as possible after an edit.  'Premake' seems to shoot at multiple platforms, but I found specifying compiler options no more enlightened than with Cmake.

It looks as though you've found a good Makefile tutor, so I'll leave my observations at that.